# C linux/fs.h Deprecated?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I'm having a issue with 
https://github.com/uzyszkodnik/rootkit

I'm trying to make it work as I'm modifying it for my class but I want to keep the file hider and it's not working when I compile it against CentOS 6.x

It throws this error:

`error: implicit declaration of function ‘dentry_path_raw’`

Here is the full error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd` modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64.debug'
  CC [M]  /root/rootkit.o
/root/rootkit.c: In function ‘file_hider’:
/root/rootkit.c:283: error: implicit declaration of function ‘dentry_path_raw’
/root/rootkit.c:283: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
make[2]: *** [/root/rootkit.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/root] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64.debug'
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Is it a build error?

Comment: What version of kernel do you have?

Comment: Linux next tree shows it include/linux/dcache.h:331:extern char *dentry_path_raw(struct dentry *, char *, int);

Comment: Yes, it's a build error and this is on CentOS 6, 2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64.debug